# out of bounds error while checking the dulipate element in array

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

i am getting OutofBounds error in it.
The outofbounds is happenning  here "if (arr[j]==arr[i])"
the program is find the dulicate numbers and make them 0.
and to shift all those dulicate numbers left.

```
input: {10,20,4,20,5}
output:{0,0,10,4,5}
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayWork
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[],n,i,j,nr=1;
        System.out.println("Enter the value for n: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        if(n>25)
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        else
        {
            arr = new int[n]; 
            System.out.println("Enter the array elements: ");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     for (j = i + 1 ; j < arr.length; j++) {
          if (arr[j]==arr[i])
          nr=arr[i];

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==nr)
                {
                    for(j=i-1;j>=0&&arr[j]>0;j--)
                    {
                        arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                    }
                    arr[j+1]=0;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The array is: ");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
}}
```

Comment: Four nested for loops? This looks suspicious to me.

Comment: I am not a pro in programming.

Answer (score 0):

That is because j = i + 1.
Probably you should change your for loops to:

```
for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     for (j = i + 1 ; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
```

But anyway, your code looks not good.

Edit: You are changing the value of i and j in the next three for loops. You should really rethink that code. But at least use a new variable in each for loop i.e. k, l, m

Comment: ok i will do it and check

Comment: same error is coming

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `i=arr.length-1`, `j=arr.length` and j is out of bounds. And hence arr[j] throws the error. change it to `i < arr.length - 1`.

Comment: i am still getting  "for ( i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
     for (j = i + 1 ; j < arr.length; j++) {
          if (arr[i]==arr[j])" same error

Comment: @ChildhoodToons I'm not completely sure, but I think its because, the inner loops change the value of i. The third nested loop and the array printing loop use i. Try using different variables there.